# How do I navigate efficiently through emacs buffer modifying lines

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am an elisp (but not programming) beginner and have some questions about the best practice to implement a function. I have written an elisp function that reformats assembler source code according to certain rules; this function currently works for a single line. It basically uses navigation within the line, looking-at and replace-match calls on subexpressions to achieve the goal.

Now I'd like to apply it to a marked region, processing the region line by line. The behaviour will be similar to the indent-region function.

What is the recommended (and efficient) way to implement this? I consider using `(line-number-at-pos ...)` applied to `(region-beginning)` and `(region-end)` to count line numbers and then move from top to bottom, working through the buffer line by line, modifying these.

Also, what would I need to preserve through this operation? I though about (save-match-data ...) and am not sure how to handle mark and point. I guess they will be useless because the text extent changed.

Comment: You might like to take a look at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19518

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html) to save and restore point and mark and [`save-restriction`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002drestriction.html) to narrow to the region.

The template would be something like this:

```
(defun my-process-region (beg end)
  "Apply `my-process-line` to every line in region."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (save-excursion
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (my-process-line)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but my understanding is that `save-excursion` also reverts modifications of the buffer, which is not what I want (the code reformats the lines). With respect to the code above: If processing changes the length of the lines, the end will not point to the right place anymore, wouldn't it?

Comment: The help says: "Save point, and current buffer; execute BODY; restore those things.Executes BODY just like `progn'. The values of point and the current buffer are restored even in case of abnormal exit (throw or error)."

Comment: Ok, I see, current-buffer does not refer to the content but the buffer. Still, end "moves" if I modify the buffer, so the "while" part does not work with the proposed test.

Comment: Should there be a `next-line` in the `while` loop?

Comment: I assumed that your line processing code advances to the next line, otherwise you need `forward-line`.

Comment: I generally recommend against using narrowing because various functions break if you use it.  Better either process the lines backward (since `beg` is unaffected by the changes) or use `(setq end (copy-marker end))` so that `end` is not a plain integer anymore but a *marker*, which will properly track the position as text is inserted/deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I accept the answer of sds. In the end, I used the code below. The reason was that I wanted entire lines available for reformatting, not just the marked region. So `(narrow-to-region)` alone would not have done the job.
I am happy to learn more, and appreciate comments on pros/cons or missing things:

```
(defun x-mode-reformat-region (beg end)
  "..."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((nlines (+ 1 (apply '- (mapcar 'line-number-at-pos `(,end ,beg)))))
          bol
          ...)
      (goto-char beg)
      (dotimes (i nlines)
        (setq bol (line-beginning-position))
        (goto-char bol)
        ;; do reformatting for this line -- uses bol for calculations
        (forward-line)))))
```

Next try -- modified based on comment. I did not find a simpler way to extend the selection to include the entire line...  any idea whether the `setq` / `narrow-to-region` combination could be simplified further (except using `(progn ...)` directly as argument ?

```
(defun x-mode-reformat-region (beg end)
  "..."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (save-excursion
      (setq beg (progn (goto-char beg) (line-beginning-position))
            end (progn (goto-char end) (line-end-position)))
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (insert "*") ;; placeholder for fancy reformatting
        (forward-line)))))
```

Comment: the way you compute `nlines` is beyond ugly. you do not need `bol`, just do `(goto-char (line-beginning-position))`. if you are afraid that your mark and point are not at the beginning of line, you should adjust the numbers you pass to `narrow-to-region`. In short, you should stay close to Emacs idioms, as in my answer.

Comment: Ok, tried to adapt the code, see edited version above. I see the point with the idioms but it is a matter of learning what these are...

Comment: Anytime you can think of an existing function which is doing something similar to what you wish to do, you can take a look at the source code for that and see how it works. Of course it might turn out to be a far more complicated example than you actually wanted, depending on how much complexity is handled by the thing you're looking at, but you'll often be able to pick up on sensible approaches to common elisp tasks in this way. `M-x find-function` is your friend. I find `C-h C-f` a convenient binding for it.